# docker on Development enviroment with compiled language (typescript)

Tags: typescript, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have 10 microservices that written on typescript, I want to run 
`docker-compose up --build` that will :

- build each container
- compile the typescript
- run each microservice with pm2

I want to be able to edit the code on my host with "vscode", and see the changes on the container

I tried to copy the files on the docker file , build them.
but when I mount the volume it overrides my code and I cant run it with pm2

docker compose

```
version: '3'
services:
  web_service_1:
    container_name: m1_container
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3014:3014
    volumes: 
      - ./:/source/m1
```

docker file

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN mkdir -p /source/m1 

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y sudo &&  apt-get install -y curl

#install node js
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

#typescript
RUN npm install -g typescript@3.2.2
#pm2 3.2.4
RUN  npm install pm2@3.2.4 -g
#text editor
RUN sudo apt-get install nano
# RUN sudo apt-get install vim

#copy project files
COPY ./m1 /source/m1

#create dist folder
RUN mkdir dist

#build the typescript
RUN cd /source/m1 && tsc

#run with pm2
CMD ["pm2-runtime", "/source/m1/ecosystem.config.js"]
```

there is any solution that I will avoid ssh to each container build and run the code?

Comment: Why are you trying to do live development inside the containers?  Especially if you don't really have special host dependencies, it's probably much easier to develop locally on your host and `docker build` a new image once your local tests pass.

Comment: I want to develop inside the container because I want all the developers on the team will have the same environment (DB , node version, etc version, python ...)

Answer (score 0):

You can run any command inside a container without going into it. Use "docker-compose exec  ". For instance, you can run "docker-compose exec web_service_1 apt-get update", that will run "apt-get update" inside the container.